# Selecting with jquery Can't manage to be specific enough

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML :

```
<div class="myclass">
    <form class="aform">
       <select name="first"></select>
       <select name="second"></select>
    </form>
</div>
```

I curently had all the div into a variable :

```
mydiv = $(".myclass");
```

Now I need to select one of the "select" tag. I tried the following query :

```
$('select[name="first"]',mydiv).html("Cool things to insert!");
```

But my jquery selection is changing both select in the form intead of changing only the one I've selected by name.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/mdBDS/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is running fine (try it at http://jsfiddle.net/wVccE/). 
If you inspect the element, you'll see that only the first `select` changed.

But I don't see any point in changing a `select` inner html, perhaps what you really want is a single `select` with multiple `option`?

Comment: Your Right, my code was running right! But I had the same name for 2 select tag in my code! :P ... The point for changind the html is depending on what entered in one field on the user form, the list will vary. So I call a php script that will generate a new option list depending on the client selection.

Comment: Ah, now I see the point. What I mean is changing the html of a select in your original code (without the option tag), which force me to view source to see that it really works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `mySelect = $(.myclass select[name="first"]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$('.myclass').find('select[name="first"]').html("Cool things to insert!");
```

See the jQuery documentation:  [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Hope this answer can help you!